# grep of string that includes a tilde returns non-matching lines

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to search for a specific string in a file. The string includes a tilde- I am trying to isolate the line that contains the string "~ ca_cert".

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=("~ ca_cert" "backup_window")
FILE=./test
for x in "${LIST[@]}"; do
  grep $x $FILE
done
```

When I run it, it returns other lines that contain tildes. For example, in a file that contains the following, it return all of the lines, when my intention is for it to only return the bottom line that contains  ~ ca_cert:

```
./test:./terraform.tfplan:  ~ update in-place
./test:./terraform.tfplan:  ~ resource "aws_db_instance" "rds_instance" {
./test:./terraform.tfplan:      ~ ca_cert_identifier                    = "rds-ca-2019" -> "rds-ca-2015"
```

Comment: For me this works.

Comment: Copy/paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and it will indicate what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is not quoting pattern i.e. `$x` in your `grep` command. That basically runs your command as `grep '~' ca_cert ./test` and finds all the lines matching `~` with an error.

However you don't really need to run a loop here. Just use `grep -f` with process substitution:

```
grep -Ff <(printf '%s\n' "${LIST[@]}") ./test
```

```
./terraform.tfplan:      ~ ca_cert_identifier                    = "rds-ca-2019" -> "rds-ca-2015"
```